# vim : how to set current buffer to a string using `:python`

Tags: buffers, vimscript-python

As example, my current buffer contains below lines

```
di=01;34
ln=01;36
mh=00
pi=40;33
```

I want to join all lines with `:`, and set entire buffer to the joined string.

How to achieve that, using `:python` command.

I tried below

```
py3 vim.current.buffer[:] = ':'.join(vim.current.buffer)
py3 vim.current.buffer = ':'.join(vim.current.buffer)
```

But neither works.

Answer (score 1):

In vimscript, just as an alternative:

```
:1,$-1substitute/$/:
:global/^/join
```

In one line with abbreviated commands:

```
:1,$-1s/$/:/ | g/^/j
```

Comment: Nice solution, though I specifically want `:python` solution. BTW, need to change `%s` to `1,$-1s` to match the `join` approach exactly. Also`keepp` and `keepj` can be used to avoid clustering search history & jumps, though only worth the effort if wrapped as a function or command.

Answer (score 0):

`vim.current.buffer` refers to a buffer object.

`vim.current.buffer[:]` on the other hand, is a list of strings containing the content of the buffer.

You can manipulate the lines of the buffer by retrieving and assigning to this list:

```
py3 vim.current.buffer[:] = [ ':'.join(vim.current.buffer[:]) ]
```

Comment: I tried your solution, still not working. error is `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation`

Comment: `:version` outputs `+python3/dyn `, invoked by `vim -u ~/tmp/.vimrc`, `cat ~/tmp/.vimrc` outputs `set nocp`.

Comment: found the answer, just change `rhs` to a list of string.

Comment: Sounds like we just need `[ ':'.join(...) ]`

Answer (score 0):

As @Mass's answer said, to set buffer content, you cannot assign to the `buffer
object` itself, you need to assign to the the sliced version, eg `vim.current.buffer[:]`.

Currently what's missing from there is, you **need to use a list of string instead
of a string** to assign to a sliced buffer object.

To summary

```
# set first line to a string
py3 vim.current.buffer[0] = "Hello world"
# replace whole buffer with a string
py3 vim.current.buffer[:] = ["a long long string"]
# replace whole buffer with two lines
py3 vim.current.buffer[:] = ["first line", "second line"]
# replace first 10 line with two lines
py3 vim.current.buffer[:10] = ["first line", "second line"]
```

Answer (score 0):

answering your precise need:

```python
vim_buffer_as_python_text = ':'.join(vim.current.buffer[:])
```

In general, you maybe want to convert the vim buffer (containing multiple lines) in a newline-separated text so:

```python
vim_buffer_as_python_text = '\n'.join(vim.current.buffer[:])
```